# How to prevent Javascript to be fired multiple times

Tags: angularjs, html, coffeescript

Hi I have a button which needs to be enabled or disabled based on a condition.
When it needs to be disabled I need to show a message. But the Javascript fires many times thus the message shows multiple times when it needs to show only once.

Below is the markup which calls the Javascript Function:-

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-save nm" ng-click="controller.saveOpportunity()" ng-disabled="!(controller.canDealBeClosedByFeeAllocationStatus() && controller.isEnabled('SaveOpportunity'))">
                <svg><use xlink:href="../Content/images/c/svg-defs.svg#circle-check"></use></svg>
                Save
            </button>
```

Below is the Javascript Function:-

```
canDealBeClosedByFeeAllocationStatus:()->
    if this.isReibDeal() && this.data.OpportunitySalesStageIsClose() == true
      if this.data.FeeAllocationComplete == false
        ShowMessage('warning', 'Fee Allocation needs to be complete')
      return this.data.FeeAllocationComplete
    else
      return true
```

What is the solution to this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

USe **ng-disabled**

```
<button ng-disabled="IsDisabled" type="submit" class="btn btn-save nm" ng-click="controller.saveOpportunity()" ng-disabled="!(controller.canDealBeClosedByFeeAllocationStatus() && controller.isEnabled('SaveOpportunity'))">
                <svg><use xlink:href="../Content/images/c/svg-defs.svg#circle-check"></use></svg>
                Save
            </button>
```

In Your Controller

```
$scope.isDisabled=false;
```

In Your Javascript function 
set `$scope.IsDisabled=true;`

When the function executed once 
set `$scope.IsDisabled=true`

Answer (score 0):

You should not have such large functions checking if something is disabled or not as ng-disabled may check that method at multiple times.

ng-disabled may be triggered for example even if you use ng-click on something unrelated to the ng-disabled method [see console in this example](https://plnkr.co/edit/YUvhScqAAmTsXtySpyCj?p=preview)

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.testClick = function(){
    console.log("click which does not affect disabled flag");
  };
$scope.isDisabled=function(){
   console.log("disabled check function triggered");
   return true
   
 };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <div>
       <button ng-click="testClick()">Test</button>
      <button ng-disabled="isDisabled()">Test</button>
      Test {{message}}
    </div>
    
  </body>

</html>
```

So a better approach is to have the ng-disable listen to a flag variable such as isDealBeClosedByFee which you can update either along the way or on controller initialization.